# Namespace using composer autoload in PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to implement the autoload feature using `psr-4` with composer but I get this error, even if I've already require it in the index. Please see the error and code below:

**Error**

> Fatal error: Class 'Blog\Classes\Database\Connection' not found in C:\wamp\www\blog-oop\index.php on line 7

**Code**

*composer.json*

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Blog\\": "app/classes/Database"
        }
    }
}
```

*Connection.php*

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Classes\Database;

class Connection{


}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Blog\Classes\Database\Connection;

$connection = new Connection;
```

*Structure*

```
>app 
  >classes
    >Database
      >Connection.php
```

Comment: Think `"Blog\\": "app/classes/Database"` should be `"Blog\\": "app"` as the namespace acts as the path to find the class.

Comment: Hi @NigelRen . I'll try it

Comment: @NigelRen . I think I just ask a stupid question. It is now working man.

Comment: I'm sure I've asked loads of stupid questions, main thing is to learn from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your composer.json

```
"Blog\\": "app/classes/Database"
```

should be

```
"Blog\\": "app"
```

as the namespace acts as the path to find the class

Comment: Hi @NigelRen . One more thing. What I only want the `Database` folder?

Answer (score 1):

i think the error occured in composer json

Instead of

```
"Blog\\": "app/classes/Database"
```

It should be

```
"Blog\\": "app/"
```

My composer.json test

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "Test",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Blog\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

app/Classes/Database/Connection.php

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Classes\Database;

class Connection {
    public function __construct()
    {
        print_r('Connection class was called');
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Connection class was called
```